# Trying to retrieve data from a Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have tried to retrieve data from Shared Preferences and tried to intent it over to my main activity where I want it to display the score the user got. There are no errors, it just doesn't save the **best_score_number_tv** or doesn't correctly send it over. I hope there isn't too much wrong :(

**Main_Screen**

```
public class Main_Screen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //SETS CUSTOM FONT
        TextView main_screen_titleone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_screen_titleone);
        TextView main_screen_titletwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_screen_titletwo);
        TextView best_score_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.best_score_tv);
        TextView best_score_number_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.best_score_number_tv);
        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LemonMilk.otf");
        main_screen_titleone.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        main_screen_titletwo.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        best_score_tv.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        best_score_number_tv.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        //******************;

        retrieveBestScore();

}


    public void startTheGame(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, press_screen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void retrieveBestScore(){
        Intent getBestScore = getIntent();
        int BEST_SCORE = getBestScore.getIntExtra("BEST_SCORE", 0);
        TextView best_score_number_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.best_score_number_tv);
        best_score_number_tv.setText(BEST_SCORE + "");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main__screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**press_screen**

```
public class press_screen extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int time_left;
    private int amountOfTapsNumber;
    private int bestScore;

    TextView amountOfTaps;
    TextView timeLeftNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_press_screen);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        timer.start();

        loadInfo();


    }

    //Create Timer


    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(21000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timeLeftNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_number_tv);
            time_left = Integer.valueOf(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString()) - 1;
            timeLeftNumber.setText(time_left + "");
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            bestScore = amountOfTapsNumber;

            TextView best_score_number_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.best_score_number_tv);

            Intent sendBestScore = new Intent(press_screen.this, Main_Screen.class);
            sendBestScore.putExtra("BEST_SCORE", bestScore);

            Intent goBackToMainActivity = new Intent(press_screen.this, Main_Screen.class);
            startActivity(goBackToMainActivity);

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_press_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void triggerTapOnMainButton(View view) {
        amountOfTaps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_of_taps);
        amountOfTapsNumber = Integer.valueOf(amountOfTaps.getText().toString()) + 1;
        amountOfTaps.setText(amountOfTapsNumber + "");
    }

    public void saveInfo(String key, int bestScore){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putInt("BEST_SCORE", bestScore);
        edit.commit();
    }

    public void loadInfo(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int BEST_SCORE = sp.getInt("BEST_SCORE", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have sharedPreferences why do you want to intent the score to main activity you can use your SharedPreferences in main activity itself to retrieve the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use and `Intent` you should put the extra in the intent you pass to 
`startActivity`

so

```
        Intent goBackToMainActivity = new Intent(press_screen.this, Main_Screen.class);
        goBackToMainActivity.putExtra("BEST_SCORE", bestScore);
        startActivity(goBackToMainActivity);
```

Alternatively you could just save the score from your press_screen activity
after

```
        bestScore = amountOfTapsNumber;
        saveInfo("BEST_SCORE", bestScore);
```

Also, if you are going to pass in a key to save the info, you might consider using it

```
    public void saveInfo(String key, int bestScore){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putInt(key, bestScore);
        edit.commit();
    }
```

And when retrieving

```
public int retrieveInt(String key){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return sp.getInt(key, 0);
}
```